# ERROR: Unrecognized name in Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, merge, scd2

I am implementing SCD 2 dimensions using MERGE statement in google cloud BigQuery.

In target table, ***is_active*** column indicates whether the record is the latest record. ***address_ref*** is the business key of each record. I am using subquery to indicate the action that need to be performed. Below is the my query:

```
MERGE `datahub-sit.dim_address` AS T
USING
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(staging.address_ref, dim.address_ref) AS address_ref,
      dim.building AS current_building,
      staging.building AS new_building,
      dim.road AS current_road,
      staging.road AS new_road,
      CASE 
        WHEN dim.address_ref IS NULL THEN 'NEW_INSERT'
        WHEN staging.building <> dim.building THEN 'UPDATE_CURRENT'
        WHEN staging.road <> dim.road THEN 'UPDATE_CURRENT'
      END
        AS MergeAction
      FROM
        `datahub-sit.staging_address` staging
      FULL JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM `datahub-sit.dim_address`
        WHERE is_active=TRUE
      ) AS dim
      ON
        staging.address_ref = dim.address_ref
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        dim.address_ref,
        dim.building AS current_building,
        staging.building AS new_building,
        dim.road AS current_road,
        staging.road AS new_road,
        'NEW_INSERT' AS MergeAction
      FROM
        `datahub-sit.staging_address` staging
      INNER JOIN
        `datahub-sit.dim_address` dim
      ON
        staging.address_ref = dim.address_ref
        AND staging.building <> dim.building
        AND staging.road <> dim.road
  ) AS S
ON T.address_ref = S.address_ref AND S.MergeAction IN ('UPDATE_CURRENT')
WHEN MATCHED AND S.MergeAction = "UPDATE_CURRENT" THEN UPDATE SET is_active=FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.MergeAction = 'NEW_INSERT' THEN
  INSERT(
    address_ref,
    building,
    block,  
    road,
    postcode,
    address_deleted,
    address_updated,
    is_active
  ) 
  VALUES(
    S.address_ref, 
    S.new_building,     
    block,
    S.new_road
    postcode,
    S.current_road,
    S.new_road,
    TRUE
  );
```

Then I got an error **Unrecognized name: block at [39:5]** in an **INSERT() VALUES()** statement. I tried to define **"T.block"** but still got an error **Unrecognized name: T at [39:5]**.

Below is the fields in **dim_address**

[image]

And **staging_address**

[image]

Is there any way to change value of some columns but the remaining columns remain the same? The idea is that I will take some new value from "source S" and keep the remaining of other columns from "target T". But when I using statement WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET, there is only values from S can be selected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to change value of some columns but the remaining columns remain the same?

Yes, I think you can use a subquery in the `INSERT()` statement to exclude the block column.

Here is updated query:

```
MERGE `datahub-sit.dim_address` AS T
USING
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(staging.address_ref, dim.address_ref) AS address_ref,
      dim.building AS current_building,
      staging.building AS new_building,
      dim.road AS current_road,
      staging.road AS new_road,
      CASE 
        WHEN dim.address_ref IS NULL THEN 'NEW_INSERT'
        WHEN staging.building <> dim.building THEN 'UPDATE_CURRENT'
        WHEN staging.road <> dim.road THEN 'UPDATE_CURRENT'
      END
      AS MergeAction
    FROM
      `datahub-sit.staging_address` staging
    FULL JOIN
      `datahub-sit.dim_address` dim
    ON
      staging.address_ref = dim.address_ref
  ) AS S
ON T.address_ref = S.address_ref AND S.MergeAction IN ('UPDATE_CURRENT')
WHEN MATCHED AND S.MergeAction = "UPDATE_CURRENT" THEN UPDATE SET is_active=FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.MergeAction = 'NEW_INSERT' THEN
  INSERT(
    address_ref,
    building,
    road,
    postcode,
    address_deleted,
    address_updated,
    is_active
  )
  SELECT
    S.address_ref,
    S.new_building,
    S.new_road,
    postcode,
    S.current_road,
    S.new_road,
    TRUE
  FROM S
  WHERE S.block IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. But I think BigQuery does not support "EXCLUDE" statement since I still got error: Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword EXCLUDE at [65:1]

Comment: I'm sorry that my interpretation may not be good. I have updated more details about my problem. So, there is no "block" in source S. While retrieving new values ​​from source S updated via target T, I want to INSERT a row that includes both the new value from S and the old value from T.